# Ordering a linked list by a value -

Tags: c, linked-list

*Please bear with me, I'm new to stackoverflow so let me attempt to explain my problem, if there are any points that I could improve on in my question making please be sure to comment and I'll edit the question*

Okay, so I've got myself a Linked list, I want to order it by a value in the list which happens to be the price:

```
tmpPtr->item->price;
```

The problem I'm having is switching the positions, here's the code:

```
struct inventory *sort_list() {
        struct inventory *tmpPtr = pFirstNode;
        struct inventory *temp = NULL;
        struct inventory *tmpNxt = pFirstNode->next;
        int tmp;
        while(tmpNxt != NULL){
               while(tmpNxt != tmpPtr){
                        if(tmpNxt->item->price < tmpPtr->item->price){
                                // if next item price is smaller than current
                                // temp for the next item
                                // heres the problem....
                                temp = tmpNxt->next;
                                tmpNxt->next = tmpPtr;
                                tmpPtr->next = temp;
                        }
                        else{
                            // if not any smaller continue    
                            tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;

                        }
                }
                tmpPtr = pFirstNode;
                tmpNxt = tmpNxt->next;
        }
        return tmpPtr; 
    }
```

The values aren't ordering as I expected from my logic, any pointers would be great
EDIT:

```
struct inventory *sort_list() {
        struct inventory *tmpPtr = pFirstNode;
        struct inventory *temp = NULL;
        struct inventory *tmpNxt = pFirstNode->next;
        while(tmpNxt != NULL){
               while(tmpNxt != tmpPtr){
                        if(tmpNxt->item->price < tmpPtr->item->price){
                                // if next item price is smaller than current
                                // temp for the next item
                                if(tmpPtr == pFirstNode){
                                    tmpPtr = pFirstNode->next; // tmpPtr is now second node
                                    pFirstNode->next = tmpPtr->next;
                                    tmpPtr->next = pFirstNode;
                                    pFirstNode = tmpPtr;
                                }

                                tmpNxt = tmpPtr->next;
                                tmpPtr->next = tmpNxt->next;
                                tmpNxt->next = tmpPtr;
                                temp->next = tmpNxt;
                        }

                }
                  temp = tmpPtr;
        }
        return tmpPtr; // Place holder
    }
```

Comment: [sigh] run under your debugger, step through, inspect variables, make notes, fix your bug/s.

Comment: I've done all this can't get my head around it, why else would I post the question @MartinJames

Comment: @Blarsssss he didn't know that. Many users are lazy. :) Can you please post a minimal example? I had implemented a sorting for lists, which might boost you up: https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/list-mergesort-c/

Comment: Why not just start with an empty linked list? Remove items from the existing list and insert them in the correct position in the new list? Might be simpler logic

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the inner if condition, you have the following state:

`Node1 -> tmpPtr -> tmpNxt -> Node2`

What you want to achieve is:

`Node1 -> tmpNxt -> tmpPtr -> Node2`

Then you have the following code:

1. `temp = tmpNxt->next;` // makes `temp = Node2`
2. `tmpNxt->next = tmpPtr;` // changes list to `Node1 -> tmpPtr <-> tmpNxt`,
3. `tmpPtr->next = temp;` // changes list to `Node1 ->tmpPtr` and `tmpNxt -> tmpPtr -> Node2`

So as you can see, you are missing the link from `Node1 -> tmpNext`. You can do that and examine your results.

Comment: I completely understand, but am still not getting the results I need

Comment: `tmpNxt = tmpPtr->next;
                                tmpPtr->next = tmpNxt->next;
                                tmpNxt->next = tmpPtr;
                                temp->next = tmpNxt;`

Comment: You need to change your code to capture `Node1` also. Then you will need to add `Node1->next = tmpNext` at the end. Note that it is easier to swap the values in the nodes than the nodes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

To swap two adjacent singly linked list members, you need three adjacent members (the one that is behind the two you want to swap), unless one of them is the head of the list.

1. Head of the list case → swap `list_head` and `list_head->next`

   ```
   assert(list_head->next);
   next = list_head->next;
   list_head->next = next->next;
   next->next = list_head;
   list_head = next;
   ```
2. Other cases → swap `cur` and `cur->next`

   ```
   assert(prev->next == cur && cur->next);
   next = cur->next;
   cur->next = next->next;
   next->next = cur;
   prev->next = next;
   ```

However, these two cases can be collapsed into a single case if the previous node is redefined to be the address of the next member of the previous node.

```
void swap_cur_with_next (node **pnext, node *cur) {
    assert(*pnext == cur && cur->next);
    node *next = cur->next;
    cur->next = next->next;
    next->next = cur;
    *pnext = next;
}

/* swap list_head with list_head->next */
swap_cur_with_next(&list_head, list_head);

/* swap cur with cur->next */
swap_cur_with_next(&prev->next, cur);
```

With a correct swap routine, it is easier to implement your bubble sort algorithm on a list. The code structure might look like this:

```
void bubble_up(node **pnext, node *cur) {
    while (cur->next) {
        if (need_to_swap(cur)) {
            swap_cur_with_next(pnext, cur);
        }
        pnext = &(*pnext)->next;
        cur = *pnext;
    }
}

node **pnext = &list_head;
while (*pnext) {
    bubble_up(pnext, *pnext);
    pnext = &(*pnext)->next;
}
```

However, as noted in a different answer, merge sort is a more natural and efficient algorithm to use to sort a list.

At the very least, you can pack the node pointers into an array, and use `qsort()` to sort the node pointers, and then link them up in sorted order afterwards.

Comment: How would I define prev?

Comment: When you traverse the list you keep track of the node behind.